# date('c') issue in Php 5.6

Tags: php, datetime, yii1.x

I am using Yii 1.6 Purchased application, hosted in Php 5.6 Server.

I have a issue in date format, software using to save date DB using code date('c'). But this code got date below format :

```
date('c') =  2016-12-28T06:32:32+00:00
```

Because above format data is not saving in DB. I want date format as :

```
2016-12-28 06:32:32
```

Manual change is code is not possible, because application use this code lot of place, So i need common settings code to get  date('c') as y-m-d h:i:s  format in php 5.6.

Answer (score 0):

```
$olddate = date('c');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($olddate));
```

Comment: Thanks, but manual implementation take place change code in lot of place .is common settings available php 5.6

Comment: you can use it as function so you can change it at one place and effect goes all placed  or instead of date('c') you can use date('Y-m-d H:i:s) also